# How to compile a numba jit'ed function with variable input type?

Tags: python, random, signature, optional-parameters, numba

Say I have a function that can accept both an `int` or a `None` type as an input argument

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

jitkw = {"nopython": True, "nogil": True, "error_model": "numpy", "fastmath": True}


@nb.jit("f8(i8)", **jitkw)
def get_random(seed=None):
    np.random.seed(None)
    out = np.random.normal()
    return out
```

I want the function to simply return a normally distributed random number. If I want reproducible results, seed should be an `int`.

```
get_random(42)
>>> 0.4967141530112327
get_random(42)
>>> 0.4967141530112327
get_random(42)
>>> 0.4967141530112327
```

If I want random numbers, `seed` should be left as `None`. However, if I do not pass an argument (so seed defaults to `None`) or explicitly pass `seed=None`, then numba raises a `TypeError`

```
get_random()
>>> TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) omitted(default=None)
get_random(None)
>>> TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) omitted(default=None)
```

How can I write the function, still declaring the signature and using `nopython` mode for such a scenario?

My numba version is 0.43.1

Comment: With numba it's always helpful for future reference and the answerers if you include your numba version. That's because the supported features can vary wildly between versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that numba in nopython mode only accepts (as of version 0.43.1) [`np.random.seed`: with an integer argument only](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/numpysupported.html#initialization).

So, unfortunately, you cannot pass in `None`.

---

The second problem is that there is (as far as I know) not a "single" signature that tells numba how to deal with missing values, however you can use two signatures (yes, it's very verbose):

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

jitkw = {"nopython": True, "nogil": True, "error_model": "numpy", "fastmath": True}

@nb.jit(
    [nb.types.float64(nb.types.misc.Omitted(None)), 
     nb.types.float64(nb.types.int64)], 
    **jitkw)
def get_random(seed=None):
    return np.random.normal()
```

Just a short explanation about the two parts of the signaure:

- The `nb.types.float64(nb.types.misc.Omitted(None))` tells numba to use `None` as default type if the argument is omitted
- and the  `nb.types.float64(nb.types.int64)` is the signature that expects an integer.

Personally I wouldn't specify the signature and simply let numba figure it out. Explicit signatures are seldom worth it in numba and more often then not they lead to slower and less flexible code.

Comment: I have experienced massive speedups when defining numpy array signatures: i.e nb.float64[:] or nb.int64[:,:], etc. but not much with regular variables.

Comment: @MottTheTuple That's interesting, because generally you don't get speedups with types in numba - except for the first call because if you don't define types the function is compiled with the given arguments while with given types the function is compiled when it's defined. The purpose of the signature is essentially "fine-grained control over types chosen by the compiler" (from http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#eager-compilation). If you have an example where the function speed is really massively different I would be very interested in an example (for example a gist).

Comment: Where I have seen this is in my linear regression function. I send in some extrema and I calculate slope,intercept and residuals all with minor numpy funcs: sum,mean,max,etc. I drop the row/s with lowest residuals. This is all done in a while statement until I reach min row #.1000 loops - python time: .0005, with nb.jit(nopython=True): .0019, nb.jit(nb.types.float64[:,:](nb.types.float64[:,:],nb.int32),
        nopython=True) time: 1.5624e-05. This is one off the top of my head, maybe not 'massive', but I have had great luck adding sigs to funcs where nopython mode performed poorly by itself.

Comment: @MottTheTuple In your timings did you exclude the first call (which includes the compilation cost)? I know a bit about the numba internals and there are few cases where typed-functions can be faster, in most cases they will be slightly slower (except when you also type if the array is contiguous). However I would appreciate it if you can create a gist (GitHub) or something else where I can have a look.

Comment: I returned to my timings and found that I did NOT exclude the first call. I tested both nopython function and both ran about the same speed. So your premise is probably correct that signatures are unnecessary in most cases.. I may have had special input types in a function I have used before that may have caused a speedup, if I find that I will send you a gist link. Thanks for the friendly discussion.

Comment: @MSeifert Just figured this out today while playing with numba.